# CPT not using archive-{post_type}.php

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a Custom Post Type set up in WordPress (code below) and an archive-team.php in my theme but when I visit example.com/meet-the-team/ its not using the archive template as it should do.

It previously was working but is no longer working and its just using the page.php template.

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_team() {

/**
 * Post Type: Team Members.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( "Team Members", "" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "Team Member", "" ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( "Team Members", "" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "has_archive" => "meet-the-team",
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "team", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "menu_icon" => "dashicons-groups",
    "supports" => array( "title", "page-attributes" ),
);

register_post_type( "team", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_team' );
```

I've flushed the permalinks and tried adding the CPT again with no joy.

Comment: What file name are you actually using? archive-team.php or archive-meet-the-team.php?

Comment: archive-team.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help/suggestions however I managed to resolve the issue.

I changed the following:

```
"rewrite" => array( "slug" => "team", "with_front" => true ),
```

to this:

```
"rewrite" => array( "slug" => "team", "with_front" => false ),
```

So the full CPT register function looks like this:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_team() {

/**
 * Post Type: Team Members.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( "Team Members", "" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "Team Member", "" ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( "Team Members", "" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "has_archive" => "meet-the-team",
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "team", "with_front" => false ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "menu_icon" => "dashicons-groups",
    "supports" => array( "title", "page-attributes" ),
);

register_post_type( "team", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_team' );
```

This is using `archive-team.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
"has_archive" => "meet-the-team",
```

is wrong.  this should either be boolean or translatable, as per [wordpress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#has_archive).  Also as stated by M Hayward, if you are going to have the archive be meet-the-team, then that needs to be the file name of your archive template.

Comment: setting the has_archive to a string/slug works for other CPTs I have in the same theme and as I mention in the question, it did work with those exact same settings before?

Comment: it works, but it's still wrong.  per the docs `If string, it should be translatable.` . Try changing your file to archive-meet-the-team.php